# The current runtime target framework is not compatible with project

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am attempting to perform an initial migration after adding `Entity Framework 7` to my Asp.Net 5 project. I am following this [documentation](http://ef.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started/aspnet5.html).

In my `project.json` I have specified:

```
  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel",
    "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnxcore50": { }
  }
```

I am attempting to execute the following command in the project directory via a command prompt:

```
dnx ef migrations add MyFirstMigration
```

But I get the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The current runtime target framework
>   is not compatible with ProjectName. The current runtime target
>   framework: 'DNX, Version=v 4.5.1(dnx451) Please make sure the runtime
>   matches a framework specified in project.json.

The weird thing is that my `project.json` is definitely targeting `dnxcore50`. I have also checked in `global.json`:

```
{
  "projects": [ "src", "test" ],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "architecture": "x86",
    "runtime": "coreclr"
  }
}
```

And my package dependencies all reference beta8:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-beta8",
    "EntityFramework.Core": "7.0.0-beta8",
    "EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-beta8",
    "Hl7.Fhir.DSTU2": "0.90.2",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.OpenIdConnect": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-beta8"
  }
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to either add `dnx451` to your project's supported frameworks, or switch to a .NET Core version.

```
  "frameworks": {
    "dnxcore50": { },
    "dnx451": { }
  }
```

Or run:

`dnvm install latest -r coreclr`

or

`dnvm use default -r coreclr`

Comment: I don't understand why it's working now. I had already specified `dnxcore50`  under frameworks in my `project.json` file. I ran `dnvm install latest -r coreclr` and it is now working. But why? The command stated that I already had the latest core CLR runtime installed.

Comment: Installing coreclr does 2 things. Install AND use. I updated above to make this clear. In the future, run `dnvm list` to see which runtime you are using. By default the "CLR" version is selected, not "CoreCLR"